# Can we construct a sine approximating function $f$ with $f'(n\pi) = 0$ and infinitely differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, numerical-methods, soft-question, fourier-analysis

Can we construct a sine approximating function $f(t) \approx \sin(t)$ with $f'(n\pi) = 0$ and infinitely differentiable?

If this requirement alone makes it too easy - which I suspect it will be - maybe we can add the requirement that we want monotonicity on each interval $$[n\pi/2,(n+1)\pi/2]$$

---

**Edit:** I am thinking of considering an error $$E(f) =\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(t)-\sin(t)|^kdt\right)^{1/k}$$

And to show that we can find an $f$ satisfying $E(f) \leq \epsilon$ (and infinitely differentiable and piecewise monotonic) for every $\epsilon > 0$.
Of particular interest would be for $k = 1,2$. Total variation and mean square.

---

**Own work**
My suspicion is that if we can, then Fourier series would be a reasonable approach as such a function would be periodic with same period as the sine has.

Comment: What do you mean by "sin approximating function"?

Comment: To quote a professor of mine, an approximation of a function is any function other than that function. :) Of course we can find an approximation, but what do you want the approximation to be? Do you want something that is easily calculated? How much error do you want to allow?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you are right, the question is probably too vague. I don't want to quantify precisely how large error I want to allow or in which sense, but rather to parametrize it somehow and show that it is possible for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: So $f(t)=\cos t $ is OK for you?

Comment: @dmtri : I updated to consider an error for the approximation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the functions
$$
 h_a(x) = \frac{a^2 x^3}{1+a^2 x^2} \, .
$$
For each $a > 0$ is $h_a$ strictly increasing, infinitely differentiable, and has a triple zero at $x=0$. Also
$$
 |h_a(x) - x| = \frac{|x|}{1+a^2 x^2} \le \frac{1}{2a}
$$
for all $x \in \Bbb R$, using the inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean.

Then $f_a(x) = h_a(\sin(x))$ is an “approximation” of $\sin(x)$ in the sense that
$$
 |f_a(x) - \sin(x)| \le \frac{1}{2a}
$$
uniformly, which implies that $E(f_a) \le (2\pi)^{1/k}/(2a)$ can be made arbitrarily small as well.

Also $f_a'(x) = f_a''(x) = 0$ at all zeros of $\sin(x)$, and $f_a$ is increasing/decreasing where $\sin(x)$ is increasing/decreasing.

As an example, $h_3$ and $f_3$ look like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmm, that was both easy and elegant. I thought something more advanced would have been needed.

Comment: You can even “transform” every zero of the sine (or any other function) into a zero of infinite order with transformations of the form $h_a(x) = x \exp(-a/|x|)$.

Comment: Hmm, reminds me of Weierstrass factorization theorem for some reason.

Comment: @mathreadler: I do not yet see the connection. With the above method you can approximate an arbitrary function $F$ by $f_a(x) = h_a(F(x))$, so that $f_a$ is arbitrarily close to $F$, has the same monotonicity, and every zero of $F$ is a multiple zero of $f_a$.

Comment: Yes, it is a good answer, very easy to understand, even simpler than I expected. I just wanted to leave some time to allow for other answers. Accepting an answer can otherwise seem to have a repelling effect on other potential answers.